# time duration calculation since from Application start deploy/run to reach midnight 12 AM in C++

Tags: c++, timer, c++17, c++14

I have requirement like time period in seconds needs to be return from the function, since from Application is deployed to reach midnight 12:00 AM in GMT. since at 12:00AM some action needs to be taken in Application. I got to know what will be the time after 12 hours, but this will not give number of hours left to reach midnight 12 AM. can you help me what will be the correct solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals; // enables the usage of 24h, 1ms, 1s instead of
                                   // e.g. std::chrono::hours(24), accordingly

    const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now =
        std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    const std::time_t t_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now - 24h);
    std::cout << "24 hours ago, the time was "
              << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t_c), "%F %T.\n") << std::flush;

    const std::time_t t_c_12 = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now + 12h);
    std::cout << "12 hours after, the time was "
              << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t_c_12), "%F %T.\n") << std::flush;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is slightly different for C++17 and C++14 as the chrono tools continue to evolve to be easier to use.

### First the C++17 solution:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using days = std::chrono::duration
    <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>>;

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = time_point_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    auto tomorrow = ceil<days>(now);
    cout << (tomorrow - now)/1s << '\n';
}
```

This prints out the number of seconds until the next 12:00am (00:00:00) UTC.

The first thing you should to do is create a custom duration `days` which is equal to 24 hours (or 86400 seconds if you prefer).

Next get the current time.  Since you want the final answer to have a precision of `seconds` it makes sense to just truncate the precision of the current time to `seconds` up front.

The next step is to truncate the precision of `now` again, but to a precision of `days`, rounding partial days **up** as opposed to down.  This is exactly what `std::chrono::ceil` does.  The resulting `time_point` `tomorrow` points to the next upcoming 00:00:00 UTC, or to *now* if `now` *is* 00:00:00 UTC.

The difference between `tomorrow` and `now` is simply the number of `seconds` until the next 00:00:00 UTC.

Note that at no time is there any translation into local time since the the input (`system_clock::now()`<sup>1</sup>) and the output (00:00:00 UTC) are both in UTC (approximately GMT as stated in the question).

The expression `(tomorrow - now)/1s` simply converts the number of seconds between `tomorrow` and `now` into an integral type so that it can be printed as the number of seconds.

### The C++14 solution:

In C++14, `std::chrono::ceil` does not yet exist.  Here is how to supply it yourself:

```
template <class To, class Rep, class Period>
constexpr
inline
To
ceil(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& d)
{
    auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<To>(d);
    if (t < d)
        return t + To{1};
    return t;
}

template <class To, class Clock, class FromDuration>
constexpr
inline
std::chrono::time_point<Clock, To>
ceil(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, FromDuration>& tp)
{
    using std::chrono::time_point;
    return time_point<Clock, To>{ceil<To>(tp.time_since_epoch())};
}
```

### The C++20 solution:

I know you didn't ask for this, but in C++20 you no longer need to convert to an integral type to stream durations out.  You can just:

```
cout << tomorrow - now << '\n';
```

And the output will look something like:

```
77094s
```

Also in C++20 if you would prefer the output to be in another format, such as hh:mm:ss, you can:

```
cout << format("{:%T}", tomorrow - now) << '\n';
```

to instead get:

```
21:24:54
```

Also, you no longer need to define your own `days` duration type.  `std::chrono::days` exists in C++20 and you can just use that.

---

<sup>1</sup> In C++14 and C++17 the epoch of `system_clock::now()` isn't specified to be aligned with 00:00:00 UTC, but in practice, every implementation does so.  [In C++20 this existing practice is specified in the standard.](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1)

Comment: Logic which you given working fine in online compiler but it is not working as expected in our Linux server we have same c++17 support there also

Comment: If you describe exactly _how_ it is not working as expected, maybe I could help.

Comment: output in online c++ compiler (https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)
No of Seconds remaining to reach midnight:79680
Tomorrow, the time was 2022-06-15 00:00:00.
current , the time was 2022-06-14 01:52:00.

Comment: output with c++14 in our local environment:
Tomorrow, the time was 2022-06-15 05:30:00.
current , the time was 2022-06-14 07:25:15.
No of Seconds remaining to reach midnight:79485

I feel in our local compiler tomorrow value is printing wrongly "auto tomorrow = ceil<days>(now)"
we have to log the time in HH::MM:SS for also for future debugging.
following statement have used for printing in HH::MM:SS format.
const std::time_t t_c1 = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tomorrow);
std::cout << "Tomorrow, the time was "<<std::put_time(std::localtime(&t_c1), "%F %T.\n") << std::flush;

Comment: for the same code with c++17 following errors while compilation in local environment. not sure ceil not available in our env.
auto tomorrow = ceil<days>(now);
error: ‘ceil’ was not declared in this scope
rror: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

Comment: If `ceil` doesn't exist in your C++17 environment, then it sounds like you don't have a full C++17 conforming environment.  You can supply `ceil` yourself as described for C++14.  If you're getting the wrong answer, you should output `time_point_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now()).time_since_epoch().count()` and see if this corresponds to the number of seconds since the Unix Time epoch as obtained by an independent source.  If not, you simply have to tell your Linux system the correct UTC time, which is done outside the scope of C++.